# i running a cookbook from github. it throws error: recipe not found but if i run other recipes from that cookbook its runs fine

Tags: chef-recipe

i took a cookbook from github and am running chef-client. it gives me the error recipe not found but if i run other recipes from that cookbook its runs fine

root@vagrant-ubuntu-trusty-64:~# chef-client
Starting Chef Client, version 12.16.42
resolving cookbooks for run list: ["task_postgis::postgre_extension"]
Synchronizing Cookbooks:
  - task_postgis (0.1.0)
  - database (6.1.1)
  - postgresql (5.1.0)
  - apt (5.0.0)
  - compat_resource (12.16.2)
  - build-essential (7.0.2)
  - seven_zip (2.0.2)
  - windows (2.1.1)
  - ohai (4.2.2)
  - mingw (1.2.4)
  - openssl (6.0.0)
Installing Cookbook Gems:
Compiling Cookbooks...
[2016-12-05T10:04:51+00:00] WARN: Chef::Provider::AptRepository already exists!  Cannot create deprecation class for LWRP provider apt_repository from cookbook apt
[2016-12-05T10:04:52+00:00] WARN: AptRepository already exists!  Deprecation class overwrites Custom resource apt_repository from cookbook apt

================================================================================

## Recipe Compile Error

### Chef::Exceptions::RecipeNotFound

could not find recipe setup_extensions for cookbook postgresql

### Cookbook Trace:

/var/chef/cache/cookbooks/task_postgis/recipes/postgre_extension.rb:1:in `from_file'

### Relevant File Content:

/var/chef/cache/cookbooks/task_postgis/recipes/postgre_extension.rb:

1>> include_recipe 'postgresql::setup_extensions'
  2:  # install extensions to database
  3:  postgresql_extension "postgis" do
  4:    database "mydb"
  5:  end
  6:
  7:  #postgresql_language "plpgsql" do
  8:  #  database "mydb"
  9:  #end
 10:

### Platform:

x86_64-linux

Running handlers:
[2016-12-05T10:04:52+00:00] ERROR: Running exception handlers
Running handlers complete
[2016-12-05T10:04:52+00:00] ERROR: Exception handlers complete
Chef Client failed. 0 resources updated in 14 seconds
[2016-12-05T10:04:53+00:00] FATAL: Stacktrace dumped to /var/chef/cache/chef-stacktrace.out
[2016-12-05T10:04:53+00:00] FATAL: Please provide the contents of the stacktrace.out file if you file a bug report
[2016-12-05T10:04:53+00:00] ERROR: could not find recipe setup_extensions for cookbook postgresql
[2016-12-05T10:04:53+00:00] FATAL: Chef::Exceptions::ChildConvergeError: Chef run process exited unsuccessfully (exit code 1)

Answer (score 0):

There is no `setup_extensions` recipe in [community postgresql cookbook](https://github.com/sous-chefs/postgresql). I'm not sure if there ever was such recipe. Where did you get this snippet?